# regex match with AND and OR operators

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to write the correct `regex` pattern to match the following condition

> (contains the word `other`) OR (contains both `us` AND `car`)

This code works as expected:

```
str_detect(c('us cars',
             'u.s. cars',
             'us and bikes',
             'other'),
           regex('other|((?=.*us)(?=.*car))',
                 ignore_case = TRUE))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, if I try to include variations of `us` (united states) such as `u.s.` and `u.s` then the pattern does not work anymore.

```
str_detect(c('us cars',
             'u.s. cars',
             'us and bikes',
             'other'),
           regex('other|((?=.*us)(?=.*u.s.)(?=.*u.s)(?=.*car))',
                 ignore_case = TRUE))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

What is the issue here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped if you intend for it to be a literal dot.  I don't know the `stringr` package well, but here is how you may do this using `grepl`:

```
x <- c('us cars', 'u.s. cars', 'us and bikes', 'other')
matches <- grepl("\\bother\\b|((?=.*\\bu\\.?s\\.?(?=\\s|$))(?=.*\\bcar\\b).*)", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Explanation of regex:

```
\\bother\\b                        match "other"
|                                  OR
(
    (?=.*\\bu\\.?s\\.?(?=\\s|$))   lookahead and assert that
                                   "us" or "u.s" or "us." or "u.s." appears
    (?=.*\\bcar\\b)                lookahead and asser that "car" appears
    .*                             match anything
)
```

The problem with your original pattern is that you never *match* anything on the RHS of the alternation.  Not a complete fix, but this:

```
regex('other|((?=.*us)(?=.*u.s.)(?=.*u.s)(?=.*car))', ignore_case=TRUE)
```

should become something like this:

```
regex('other|((?=.*us)(?=.*u.s.)(?=.*u.s)(?=.*car).*)', ignore_case=TRUE)
                                                  ^^^ add this
```

Comment: thanks tim but even if I do not escape it, `.` includes `\\.` so my code should work

Comment: on a side note dont you miss a parenthesis after `other` in your code? here the logical conditions looks like (other OR u.s). Am I missing something?

Comment: ahhh! thanks for the fix but why is that? I dont understand? I thought the lookahead would not consume anything so I can add as many as I want as in R. And my first try is working in the simplest case.. very strange

Comment: I don't know your API well.  The regex pattern I used in `grepl` seems correct to me.

Comment: ok thanks. lets just forget about this API for now. Could you just please explain your pattern? It looks a little bit different than mine

Comment: It just matches `other` or both `us` and `car`.  Note carefully that I place word boundaries around each word.  You want to match `other` but not `others`.